# Python "for loop" with 2 lists/variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following code:

```
def odraw(oposlist, osizelist):
    for opos in oposlist and osize in osizelist:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (opos[0], opos[1], osize[0], osize[1]))
```

How to rephrase the second line? How it is written right now obviously does not match the Python syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
for i in range(len(oposlist)):
    # Refer oposlist and osizelist like
    oposlist[i]
    osizelist[i]
```

Tbh, other answer is better :-)

Comment: Not always better ;-) E.g., in list comprehension I'd prefer iterating over indexes cause it's just more compact.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for pairwise iteration, use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for opos, osize in zip(oposlist, osizelist):
```

If, however, you want the cartesian product (pair every element in `oposlist` with every element in `osizelist`), use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) ...

```
from itertools import product
# ...
for opos, osize in product(oposlist, osizelist):
```

... or simply nest loops:

```
for opos in oposlist:
    for osize in oposlist:
        # do stuff
```